# Constructing DTO:s with Querydsl and ConstructorExpression.create()

Tags: java, querydsl

I have a problem involving querydsl and DTO:s

I have some query object:

```
QPerson person = QPerson.person;
QExamCode examCode = QExamCode.examCode;
QExamGrade examGrade = QExamGrade.examGrade;
QProgram gradeProgram = examGrade.program;
```

From them I try to query and list instances of a DTO class (that is not an entity) that is called CompletedCreditsSummary.
CompletedCreditsSummary has a constructor which takes: Long,Long,Float.

```
JPQLQuery query = new JPAQuery(manager);
query = query.from(person, examCode, examGrade);
query = query.where(person.studies.examGrades.contains(examGrade).and(examGrade.examCode.eq(examCode)).and(examGrade.passed.isTrue()));
```

I am able to do this (Without group by and with CompletedCreditsSummary requiering all the parameters it needs to be able to create person and program objects, in this case simplified to person.id and program.id)

```
ConstructorExpression.create(CompletedCreditsSummary.class,person.id,program.id,examCode.credits);

return   query.list(completedCreditsSummaryExpression);
```

This works. But when I want to add this to the query:

```
query.groupBy(person, examGrade.program);
```

and create CompletedCreditssummary with examCode.credits.sum() i.e.

```
ConstructorExpression.create(CompletedCreditsSummary.class,person.id,gradeProgram.id,examCode.credits.sum());
```

instead of

```
ConstructorExpression.create(CompletedCreditsSummary.class,person.id,gradeProgram.id,examCode.credits);
```

I get a: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch.

The question here is what the difference between examCode.credits (NumberPath) and examcode.credits.sum() (NumberExpression) and what I could do to solve my problem.

As I am learning querydsl by trial and error there is probably something fundamental that I have overlooked. Would really appreciate any help!

Regards Rasmus

EDIT: Preferably I would something like this to work (with group by and CompletedCreditsSummary constructor taking Person,Program,Float.):

```
ConstructorExpression<Person> personExpression = ConstructorExpression.create(Person.class,person.id);
ConstructorExpression<Program> programExpression = ConstructorExpression.create(Program.class,gradeProgram.id);
ConstructorExpression<CompletedCreditsSummary> completedCreditsSummaryExpression = ConstructorExpression.create(CompletedCreditsSummary.class,personExpression,programExpression,examCode.credits.sum());
```

EDIT: Got it to work by having the CompletedCreditsSummary Constructor accepting: Long,Long,Number. That is I changed Float to Number. This is not an ideal solution but at least it works.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(manager);
query.from(person, examCode, examGrade)
  .where(
    person.studies.examGrades.contains(examGrade),   
    examGrade.examCode.eq(examCode),
    examGrade.passed.isTrue())
  .groupBy(person, examGrade.program)
  .list(ConstructorExpression.create(
    CompletedCreditsSummary.class, 
    person, examGrade.program, examCode.credits.sum()));
```

You need to make sure that the argument for ConstructorExpression after the class are compatible with the arguments to the constructor you want to invoke. Replacing entities with ids caused your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw now that I left out an important detail. The completedCreditsSummary takes all the necessary parameters to be able to create person and program objects. This is the only way I got it to work. I have narrowed the problem (difference between the listing working and not working) to examCode.credits (without groupby) working. and examCode.credits.sum() (with grouping) not working. And to clarify: The CompletedCredits constructor takes: Long, Long, Float but I would like it to handle Person,Program,Float

Comment: Maybe you need to join to examcode.credits to be able to use it in the projection. I don't understand your problem with the constructor.

Comment: I got it to work with the CompletedCreditsSummary receiveing an Number instead of a Float in it's constructor. Seem that the returned value from sum() can't be interpreted as a Float. Even sum().floatValue() Does not return a float. Is not that supposed to work?

Comment: @Rasmus I couldn't reproduce the issue with the Float argument. Could you post the stacktrace maybe in a GitHub ticket for the Querydsl project?

Comment: Ok, will do that as soon as I got the time.